# How can I be proficient at fishing?

Tags: fantasy-life

In Fantasy Life one of your lives (read as Jobs) can be that of an angler or fisherperson. In the other mini games for gathering resources or creating items you can get bonuses from doing it quickly, like cooking can yield a better dish or multiple dishes per attempt. In fishing there is the chance of catching larger fish, fish that you can use as trophies (might be the same thing?) and just rare fish in an area.

The introduction of the fishing quests you have to find one of the rare ones and the cat known as Trout shows you a location near an Apple tree to catch an Applefish. I went back on my own and the fish was not there. Later on after some random fishing I finally caught another but there was no apple tree in sight. Was this just a misleading storyline that the environment has an impact more than 'These fish are found in those zones'? (Which you can look up in the library for what its worth).

Also, does the time it takes to catch the fish have any bearing on what kind of fish? If I catch it fast will it be bigger or by their nature is it the longer ones to catch will be bigger?

I guess the end all question is what can I do as a player to be the best I can be at fishing?

Comment: I am pretty sure how long it takes to catch is determined at the start of reeling in. Certain fish and sizes are just harder to catch than others. And maybe the area just needs to have an apple tree, not necessarily "nearby".

Comment: Hitting A quickly after the fish is hooked will deal extra damage.  From my experiences, the bigger fish take longer to catch.  This usually means stopping to release tension in the line, which is where the difficulty is coming in.

Answer (score 1):

The time used to catch the fish is not relevant because the fish is chosen by the game when you first pull your rod, hence the HP bar becomes easy or difficult to pull.

Each area has like 3-4 types of fish, and maybe two of then can be caught in giant size.

And to be better at fishing you just have to fish a lot and in tougher places, so you can level up faster.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking of a more complete question:

The only fishes you can use as trophy are Lordfishes, those "boss fish" that show over the water and are unique to some fishing spots. Doesn't matter if you fish a Giant-sized of any other fish, you can't trophy them.

Yes, the Applefish story-related fishing spot is just that, story-related. You can fish Applefish anywhere on Castele, AFAIK. Also, an Applefish is just a very rare fish that can be caught in South Castele and East Grassy Plains.

The time it takes to catch a fish depends on what fish you're fishing. It's random, depends on your luck, and the game determines the fish as soon as you start fishing. So one way to "farm" for rare fish is: see if the one you're getting is too easy, if so let it go and fish again. If you catch a fish really fast it just means it's a really common fish you'll be getting.

As MurifoX said, the only thing to be better at fishing is fish at harder spots - but I'll add to it: complete the challenges and move up as fast as you can. If you've already done the challenge for the common fish at that level, and you start fishing something that's too easy, let it go and start over again to see if you can get a rarer fish.